# Javascript Animation on Canvas and Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm toying around with some canvas and simple animation - I had a simple class for rendering my map.

```
 var Map = Class.extend({
        init: function () {
            //Setup stuff       
        },
        DrawMap: function (canvas, camera) {
            //Render the map
        }
    });
```

my core application code is also in class

```
 var App = Class.extend({

        init: function (canvas) {
             //Load Stuff
        },

        GameLoop: function () {
            this.map.DrawMap(this.canvas, this.camera);
        }

    });
```

Now using the code below this works fine and my map renders.

```
    var canvasMap = document.getElementById('cmap');

    app = new App(canvasMap);

    setInterval(function () {
        app.GameLoop();
    }, 100);
```

However - I understand this is not ideal and am trying to convert to this (http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) So I adjusted my code.

I added the code above to my index page

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          function (/* function */callback, /* DOMElement */element) {
                              window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                          };
```

And changed my init code (Used to use Set Interval to)

```
    var canvasMap = document.getElementById('cmap');

    app = new App(canvasMap);

    requestAnimFrame(function() { app.GameLoop(); });
```

Now based on some debugging what happens here is the App.GameLoop method is called once (I added a log to the game loop method). And then is not called again. I imagine this is done to my in experience with the JS objects. My background is in C# so this is relatively new to me.

Any reason as to why this would be called just once?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this, I missed the Recursion.

```
   var initAll = function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var canvasMap = document.getElementById('cmap');

            app = new App(canvasMap);
            mainLoop();
        });
    };

    var mainLoop  = function() {
               requestAnimFrame(mainLoop);
                app.GameLoop();
    };
```